# find if item exists in a list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list:

```
<ul id="coll-selected-list" class="droptrue sort-drop ui-sortable">
              <li class="sortedli" style="">blah</li>
              <li class="sortedli" style="">blee</li>
              <li class="sortedli" style="">blu</li>
              <li class="sortedli" style="">blum</li>
</ul>
```

I want to check it item blah exists in the above list. However my code doesn't work, any ideas?

```
var itemName = "blah";
           if ($("#coll-selected-list li:contains(" + itemName + ")").length) {
               alert("exists");
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotes :

```
if ($('#coll-selected-list li:contains("' + itemName + '")').length) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if the element exists by [filtering](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) element based on their [inner text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and seeing how many elements match the filter:

```
var exists = $("#coll-selected-list > li")
                 .filter(function() { return $(this).text() == "blah" })
                 .length
             != 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemName = "blah";
           if ($("#coll-selected-list li:contains('" + itemName + "')").length>0) {
               alert("exists");
           }​
```

you are missing the quotes from the contains

Answer (score 0):

Missing quotes from contains

```
var itemName = "blah";
if ($('#coll-selected-list li:contains("' + itemName + '")').length) {
    alert("exists");
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsbin.com/unakag/edit#preview)